# Saving data to notepad and compiling additional saves into existing data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a winform app that has 25 buttons that increase a counter on 25 labels above each button. What would be the best way to use a save button on click event to save the current values of the labels to a comma-delimited text file such that the first save creates the file and each additional save overwrites it?

Info: Assume the labels are named label1-label25 for simplicity, the text file will be named appDataFile, and that the save button will be named button26.

Example: On initial save, the winform app will create appDataFile and populate 25 values separated by commas. On any additional save it will then take the current value (let's say label1 was 5 already and its new value is 7) and will then overwrite the data in the text file and be left still with 25 values but the first being label1 will now be 12

Comment: combine all values you want to store into a string variable and then use [`File.WriteAllText(filename, aString);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Could you explain a bit about the background? Because it sounds a bit odd that the values in the UI and file does not match.

Comment: @JonasH Its basically a simple tracker app i want to add onto. right now you click button1 and it makes label1 go from 0 to 1. one click increases the count by 1. what i want to do is be able to save this data to a txt file before closing the app(via a save button). but i want to keep a running total of every time it is saved so the first time if label1 value was 5 second save is 7 third save is 10 then i want the txt file to hold 22 and not just the most current save

Comment: @Wyck yeah i kinda understand the baseline of how it all works as im not new to coding, but i think im getting hung up more on how to do the additional saves that will tally up the data. i know itll be something like reading the file using a line split for the comma and then maybe looping through the array to make the data numeric? adding it up and then resaving it to the file. or making it numeric in the first place im not 100% sure how data from notepad is read back to winforms

Comment: Still don't know what part of this you're stuck on.  But you may find this piece of code useful:  it produces a comma-separated list of the text of 25 numbered labels:  `string csv = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Select(index => ((Label)this.Controls.Find($"label{index}", false)[0]).Text));`